# Cannot submit form using python requests

Tags: python, forms, python-requests

I have been trying to submit form request but can't. I tried to send using Request library. I am not able to figure out the parameters to be sent.
There is just a textarea and submit button.
Here is the website source:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<input id="RId" type="hidden" value="Some_XYZ_Code" />
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div id="TextContainer" class="textarea-container">
  <textarea id="Text" rows="5" maxlength="700" class="abc"></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <button id="Send" class="btn btn-primary-outline" type="button"   onclick="SendMsg()" data-loading-text="Loading..."><span class="icon icon-pencil"></span> Send</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

My Code goes like:

```
import requests
r = requests.post("https://akshitdhar.sarahah.com/",
              data={'id':'RId','value':'Some_XYZ_Code','Text':'abc'})
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: That can't be the website source, as none of the fields have `name` attributes. Are you sure the form is being submitted directly?

Comment: If you look carefully it is not submitting the form, it is calling JS function SendMsg() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting message to Sarahah:

```
def makePost2User(userId, msg):
    r = requests.get("https://%s.sarahah.com/" % userId);

    if (r.status_code != 200):
        print("Error making GET Request. Server returned Code: %s" % r.status_code)
        pass

    cookie = r.headers['Set-Cookie'].split(";")[0]
    print("Cookie: %s" % cookie)
    headers = { 'Cookie': cookie }

    tstr = r.content.decode().split("<input id=\"RecipientId\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"")[1]
    uId = tstr.split("\"")[0]
    print("UserID: %s" % uId)

    tstr = r.content.decode().split("name=\"__RequestVerificationToken\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"")[1]
    rToken = tstr.split("\"")[0]
    print("Token: %s" % rToken)

    url = "https://%s.sarahah.com/Messages/SendMessage" % userId
    data = { "__RequestVerificationToken":rToken, "userId": uId, "text": msg }

    p = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print("Posted. Server returned Code: %s" % p.status_code)
    pass
```